# Infinite loop of expected declarations in Xcode 8 swift 3

Tags: swift

This is the code. On the last closing parentheses I get:

> Expected "," declaration

and it's infinite. You put it and then the error is you have to delete. Whats wrong? I have tried closing and opening Xcode multiple times.

```
{

@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func createAccountTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let username = usernameTextField.text
    let password = passwordTextField.text

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: username!, password: password!, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil{
            let errorMessage = error?.localizedDescription

            // error creating account
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error" , message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present( alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {

        // success
            if ((Error.self != nil)) {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Nice!", message: "Ok, now that you have an account, let's go to the Log In screen", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
            let ViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")
            self.present(ViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            }
        }
}
```

There is also something else at the beginning but Stack Overflow doesn't accept that much code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no closing parenthesis on `Auth.auth().createUser(....)`

Just to be sure on terminology: This is a closing parenthesis `)` and this is a closing brace `}`. You may have too many of the latter.

Comment: Actually, I just checked the code is good. It keeps asking for declarations.

Comment: If this is all the relevant code, you're missing a closing brace AND a closing parenthesis.  Double-click on the opening brace of the completion block and you'll see it.

Comment: It expects a comma because it expects an argument after the completion because you're parentheses aren't matched.